# can a array be stored in a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am curious, can an array be stored in a function? when i declare an array within my function. It errors out as the value can not be read, once i take it out of the function then the value can be read.

```
function decades(e) {
  var decadesArray = ["one decade",
  "two decades",
  "three decades",
  "four decades",
  "five decades",
  "six decades",
  "seven decades",
  "eight decades",
  "nine decades",
  "millennium"];

  for( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
      console.log("decadesArray[0]");
    }
  }
}
```

decades(i);

Comment: It can, in a few ways, can you elaborate, share your code, explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by stored. If you mean is it a living object that can change once the function exits then no (unless it is created based on external sources), the array will be recreated each time the function is ran. Also if you are creating an array inside a async callback you won't be able to access its set value if your code trying to do the accessing is not part of the callback process.

Comment: Sure I posted the code, I am new to javascript still. I am trying to wrap my head around how to do this. I basically want to loop 1-100. every "decade" to print 1-9 decades and 10th being a millennium. I thought the best way for me to be able to print these strings dynamically would be to store them in an array, then pull those out when a "decade" gets printed.

Comment: Can you show the actual code that is producing the error - including the code that calls the function and the error message itself

Comment: I found out when I console.logged decadesArray the function accepted the Array, but now its coming back as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is inside your if statement to [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)/[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) off one of the array elements each time the if statement is true. In your case you would shift the first array element each time.

```js
function decades(e) {
  var decadesArray = ["one decade",
  "two decades",
  "three decades",
  "four decades",
  "five decades",
  "six decades",
  "seven decades",
  "eight decades",
  "nine decades",
  "millenium"];

  for( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log("Year: ",i);
    //check if i is greater than 0
    //otherwise when i is 0 will be considered
    //the first decade
    if (i % 10 == 0 && i>0) {
      console.log( decadesArray.shift(), i );
    }
  }
}
decades();console.log( decadesArray[i/10] || i );
```

If you aren't wanting to actually pull of each element of the array you can just use `(i-10)/10` as an index into the array and print that out and if that index ends up being `undefined` then just print the number.

```js
function decades(e) {
  var decadesArray = ["one decade",
  "two decades",
  "three decades",
  "four decades",
  "five decades",
  "six decades",
  "seven decades",
  "eight decades",
  "nine decades",
  "millenium"];

  for( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log( decadesArray[(i-10)/10] || i );
  }
}
decades();
```

Comment: Thats really close to what i'm trying to do, I wanted it to go through all the numbers though. So I could see 1-100, and every multiple of 10 prints out "decades"

Comment: @Ilyris then just put a `console.log()` outside the if that prints the number (see edit). Note the log view in the snippet is limited so look in the actual browser console for full output

Comment: Oh! nice! Lastly I just need to figure out a way to swap out that year: 10 for one decade. and year: 20 for two decade. I'll try to figure that out though :D  So, to print the remaining numbers out console.log(i) has to be before the conditional statements?

Comment: it can be before or after, it just can't be within the if statement as the if statement tells limits the number of times that part gets called.

Comment: (i-10)/10] || i    -> So this is confusing to me, I don't know if i quite understand this... Is this i minus 10 divide by 10 or i?

Comment: it is i minus 10 then divided by 10, it is to make sure the decade isn't printed until the correct i. For instance when i is 20 that means 2 decades so i - 10 is 10 then when divided by 10 it is 1 which is the second index into the array (since arrays are 0 indexed). And the `|| i` is for when that formula doesn't end up being a whole number (ie 2.4). When that happens it is `decadesArray[2.4]` which doesn't have a value as that isnt a valid index so just `i` is printed

Comment: That is incredible... Is this used often? that algorithm to pull array values?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? If not, please try to be more clear.

Please note that in the StackOverflow snippet console. the maximum number of lines shown is limited. That's why output seemingly starts in like the fifties numbers.

```js
function decades() {
  var decadesArray = ["one decade",
  "two decades",
  "three decades",
  "four decades",
  "five decades",
  "six decades",
  "seven decades",
  "eight decades",
  "nine decades",
  "millennium"];

  for( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 10 == 0 && i > 0) {
      console.log(decadesArray[Math.trunc(i/10)-1]);
    } else {
      console.log(`Year: ${i}`)
    }
  }
}
decades();
```

Comment: This also Is the exact same thing I was trying to do, just coded a bit differently. Still helps to expose me to different way of doing things. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another approach reversing the loops. Loop over decades array and loop 10 times inside it. Using `slice()` on the array allows passing in 1-10 decades to display

```js
function decades(e=10) {
  var decadesArray = ["one decade",
    "two decades",
    "three decades",
    "four decades",
    "five decades",
    "six decades",
    "seven decades",
    "eight decades",
    "nine decades",
    "millennium"
  ];
  decadesArray.slice(0,e).forEach(function(text, di) {
    var start = di * 10 + 1;
    for (var i = start; i < start + 10; i++) {      
        console.log('year: ', i)
    }
    console.log(text);
  });
}

decades()
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript function will initialize only when it is called, all private variable inside the function will activated only for that time.

You need to assign variable outside the function to keep stored assigned value in variable.

```js
var decadesArray = ["one decade",
  "two decades",
  "three decades",
  "four decades",
  "five decades",
  "six decades",
  "seven decades",
  "eight decades",
  "nine decades",
  "millenium"
];

decades(0);

function decades(e) {

  decadesArray.push("New value stored 1");
  decadesArray.push("New value stored 2");
  decadesArray.push("New value stored 3");


  for (var i = 0; i < decadesArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(decadesArray[i]);
    document.getElementById('logVw').innerHTML += decadesArray[i] + '<br>';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='logVw'>
</div>
```